# how to count the lower triangle elements in a matrix

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix. Suppose I have a list of a lower triangular matrix. How can I count the number of the elements in the matrices?

For example,

```
Matrix <- c(0, 4, 3, 1, 2,
            0, 0, 3, 2, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 2, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Matrix <- matrix(Matrix, 5, 5)

> Matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    4    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    0    0    0
[4,]    1    2    2    0    0
[5,]    2    1    1    1    0
```

How to count the number of the elements in this matrix? 
This matrix contains 10 elements. How to count it in R?

Comment: r u looking for `sum(abs(Matrix) > 0)`?

Comment: Such a matrix should usually be stored as a sparse matrix: `library(Matrix); Matrix <- Matrix(Matrix)`. You can then get the number of entries as `length(Matrix$x)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a matrix of size n x n, the number of elements in the lower triangle is

n * (n - 1) / 2

Comment: To clarify, this is for a strictly triangular matrix (triangular matrix where all diagonal elements are 0).

Comment: Suppose I have a list of continuous integers `T` from `0` to `N` where `N = (n * (n - 1)) / 2`. How do I get the row and column index when given a value in `T`?

Answer (score 2):

We can get the lower triangle elements using the function `lower.tri` and then we can sum over them to count number of elements.

```
sum(lower.tri(Matrix))
#[1] 10
```

where

```
lower.tri(Matrix) #returns

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```